# How to make my asp:button longer with width?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to make my asp:button longer. I've tried putting width in the code itself. This is the original Code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server"  Cssclass="btn" onclick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Login" ></asp:Button>
```

I've tried putting it in C#.

```
<script runat="server">

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         btnLogin.Width = 700;
    }

</script>
```

I've also tried CSS

```
.form-container .btn {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 20px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:1000%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
```

I've also tried to put the width in the button code itself with

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server"  width="700px" onclick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Login" ></asp:Button>
```

Nothing is working and I'm out of ideas as to what to do. Anybody else have any thoughts?

Comment: This `Width="700px"` should work by alone. I think you missed something else here, maybe this width override from other css or something?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache ?

Comment: some other script probably have set the button width using the !importan element - and thats why nothing works for you. Check the other css code that you have on your page

Comment: @ywwy i cleared my cache, I'll check the code again and see if theirs somthing messing with the width

Comment: @Airizzo, go into developer mode of your browser, where you can check the css rules that impact the button.

Comment: @ywwy i just did that, I apparently had set it that boxes inside my form could only have a max of 280%. Dunno how that translates into PX, but once I found that I remembered I could just switch it to px and work my way down in the other boxes/buttons. Thanx you guys and gals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very beginning of my code, I put in a max-width in my CSS. That was over riding everything I was trying. The following code shows what it looks like.

```
input, select, textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

I then raised the max width too 315, and that allowed me to get the login bar even to the close form bar. The code I did was this. First is my CSS max code, and then my asp Code.

```
input, select, textarea {
    max-width: 315px;
}

<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" width="315px" Cssclass="btn" onclick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Login" ></asp:Button>
```

That's how I fixed it. I also had to redo the input fields in the form, but was just a easy edit of width.

Answer (score 0):

It seems  you are using bootstrap.
check max-width property of input in bootstrap.css

Comment: I don't use any bootstrap in any application. I don't have the time to learn it, so I steer away from it. Thank you.